# While loop is not working in document db stored procedure

Tags: javascript, database, azure, document, procedure

I have a bellow code in my stored procedure , but azure is throwing an exception
"maximum allotted time limit exceed" whenever I have while loop with true condition. Unless and until unique validation performed I don't wanna proceed further execution.

```
if (field.validations.unique != undefined && field.validations.unique) {
            var gotResponse = false;
            var query = "select * from root r where r." + field.name + "='" + record[field.name] + "' AND r.obj_type = '" + record.obj_type + "'";
            var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, {}, function (err, existingDocs, responseOptions) {
                if (existingDocs.length > 0 && existingDocs[0].id != record.id) {
                    if (!record.error['unique'])
                        record.error['unique'] = [];
                    record.error['unique'].push(field.name);
                }
                gotResponse = true;
            });
            while(true){
                    if(gotResponse ) break;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Not working? `gotResponse` never changes, what did you expect?

Comment: ya.. but any reason?

Comment: is there any way to make the call to " collection.queryDocuments()" sync instead of asynchronous?  bcoz I dont want to proceed the execution without callback response.

Comment: No, just handle everything in the callback.

Comment: logicality the while loop is not infinite loop, after callback   it will change gotResponse  and loop should break.but that is  not happening .

Comment: By the logic, it is infinite. Your `while` loop blocks any other JS execution, and the callback never gets a chance to be executed.

Comment: ohhhhh.. so that was the main reason .

Comment: another solution I had involves setInterval function, but again azure throws exception that  setInterval  not defined . any idea about that?

Comment: You can't get this to behave in synchronous manner. Just create the logic according to the fact, that the code is asynchronous.